# Replacing a dimmer switch with regular

Tags: electrical, switch

[image]

Replacing a dimmer switch that is 1.)  broken 2.) not only dims the lights but also the fan speed. There are two switches. One I do not know what it operates but has a jumper wire from the dimmer to the bottom screw, a black wire on the top screw (same side), a red wire on the left side and nothing connected to the green screw. The dimmer has three wires coming out of it. Black #1.) is spliced into the red and black wire coming from the wall; Black #2.) is spliced into the jumper wire to the mystery switch; Green spliced into bare from the wall. I purchased a three screw switch: 2 golden screws on the right and then a green screw on the left. Where do I put each wire? Black on the top screw with a jumper running to the other switch, red on the bottom, and bare to green screw?

Comment: Is that switch single pole or 3-way?

Comment: And *which* wires from the wall is Dimmer Black #1 spliced to?

Comment: It looked like that might be set up as double gang so the fan and light can each have there own switch.  Take another pic with the second switch out and a clear view of what's connected to what.

Comment: Found out the switch controls a light in the hallway, not on the fan. I'm not sure how to post an additional picture after initial. Which colored wire goes on each post on the new switch (Two golden screws on the right and then the green ground on the left)?

Answer (score 1):

The same two wires that connect to the dimmer connect to the new switch. Ground is extra, but for switching purposes, the two wires connected to the dimmer connect to the switch. Polarity, or which is which don't matter.

Comment: On the dimmer switch there were two black wires and a green. One of the black wires was connected to the other switch. The other black wire had a red and black wire spliced into it. I know the green/bare wire connects to the green screw of the switch. But where do I put the black and red wire and the jumper wire?

Comment: Green to green... The black and red don't make a difference.   The wire from the other switch is the power feed, the red is the load... Your new switch doesn't care which is which.   The wire from the other switch goes on one term of the new switch, the red wire goes on the other switch term.  The green or bare are the ground...